# Print pattern in MIPS

Tags: loops, mips, sequence

How to print the following two patterns in **MIPS**:

a)
1
12
123
1234
12345

b)
1
22
333
4444
55555

Thanks!!

Comment: Can you do it in C?  If not, then you need an algorithm.  If so, then where are you stuck with MIPS?

Answer (score 0):

```
Part a)

.data
    prompt: .asciiz "enter range: "
    space: .asciiz " "
    newline: .asciiz "\n"
    

.text
.globl main

    main:
        
        #li $t2, 0  
        li $t1, 6
        li $t2, 1
        li $t3, 6
        
        

        
    for:
        
        beq $t2, $t3, end   
        addi $t2, $t2, 1    

        li $t0, 1   # count = 0

        while:
            
            beq $t0, $t2, newlineloop   
            move $a0, $t0

            # printing result
            li $v0, 1
            syscall
            
            addi $t0, $t0, 1

            
            

            j while

    newlineloop:
        li $v0, 4
        la $a0, newline
        syscall
        j for


    
        

    end:
        li $v0, 10
        syscall


Part b)

.data
    prompt: .asciiz "enter range: "
    space: .asciiz " "
    newline: .asciiz "\n"
    

.text
.globl main

    main:
        
        #li $t2, 0  
        li $t1, 6
        li $t2, 0
        li $t3, 5
        
        

        
    for:
        
        beq $t2, $t3, end   
        addi $t2, $t2, 1    

        li $t0, 0   # count = 0

        while:
            
            beq $t0, $t2, newlineloop   
            move $a0, $t2

            # printing result
            li $v0, 1
            syscall
            
            addi $t0, $t0, 1

            
            

            j while

    newlineloop:
        li $v0, 4
        la $a0, newline
        syscall
        j for


    
        

    end:
        li $v0, 10
        syscall
```

Answer (score 0):

```
.data
newl:  .asciiz "\n"

.text

#Code example

.globl main

main:

li $t0,1

li $t1,6



loop:

beq $t0,$t1,endloop

li $t2,1

loop2:

beq $t2,$t1,endloop2

move $a0,$t2

li $v0,1

syscall


addi $t2,1

j loop2

endloop2:

addi $t0,1

li $v0,4

la $a0,newl

syscall


j loop

endloop:


li $t0,1

li $t1,7

li $t2,1

loop3:

beq $t0,$t1,endloop3

li $t2,1

loop4:

beq $t2,$t0,endloop4

move $a0,$t2

li $v0,1

syscall

addi $t2,1

j loop4

endloop4:

li $v0,4

la $a0,newl

syscall

addi $t0,1

j loop3

endloop3:


li $v0,10
syscall
```